# How do I save outputs of a variable in a loop to a text file in python in columns?

Tags: python, text-files

I am generating random edges from a graph and printing them, but every time I try to save it to a text file, I end up with errors like `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`. The code is below:

```
import re
import md5
import pickle
import networkx as nx
import itertools
from random import choice

ff=open("testfile.txt","r+")
G=nx.read_gpickle("authorgraph_new.gpickle")
for nodes in G:
    random_edge=choice(G.edges())
    ff=open("testfile.txt","a")
    ff.write(random_edge)
```

I need to save the outputs of random_edge in a text file preferably in columns, as the value of `random_edge` is in the form `(abcdef, pqrstu)`. I want to put the two in separate column in the same line and the next value in the same columns. I know I can use the `"\n"` to get the outputs to newline but when I used

```
ff.write(random_edge + "\n")
```

I get an error `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`.

Comment: You probably want to use `print(..., file=ff)` instead of `ff.write(...)`.  (I'm assuming you are using Python 3.x.)

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what you need to know. `random_edge` is a tuple, "\n" is a string. What do you expect the result of `tuple + string` to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you may have a try to do it in 2 lines like:

```
for nodes in G:
    ff.write(random_egde)
    ff.write('\n')
```

hope this would work for your case.
here first line writes your data while the second line adds a new line to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Joel's comment is correct: you're concatenating your result (a tuple) with the newline character, a string. Python doesn't like mixing datatypes that way. If you're writing more complex structured data, then in the future you may want to look into python's csv module as well.